# How to install a TMS component from old versions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-10-seattle, tms

Previously I worked on a project in `Delphi XE7` and now want to open and edit it in `Delphi 10 Seattle`. I had used `TMS component pack` but my old TMS is for `Delphi XE7`. Actually, I don't want to buy a newer version but want to use some of that old version components. Is there any way?

Comment: Do you have the source code? If so, you can probably just compile it again. If not, you have to buy the upgrade because .dcu and .bpl files are not compatible across versions. In either case, contact TMS for support with their components.

Comment: FYI, there is no Delphi version named `Delphi XE 10 Seattle`, it's only `Delphi 10.x “Cityname“`. Last Delphi version with XE was Delphi XE 8.

Comment: Yes, I have the pas files and I've added them to a new package but when I try to install the package I'm facing many errors like this:  [dcc32 Error] Package1.dpk(41): E2200 Package 'asgdxe9' already contains unit 'AdvGrid'

Answer (score 1):

Open a Windows Explorer and navigate to your TMS component pack installation folder. There open the file **tmsdefs.inc** with a text editor of your choice.

You should **NOT** be able to find `{$IFDEF VER290}` or `{$IFDEF VER300}`, since they would be the entries for `Delphi XE8` respectively `Delphi 10 Seattle`!

Search for `{$IFDEF VER280}`, that's the entry for `Delphi XE7`, and copy the whole section as far as to the corresponding `{$ENDIF}`. Paste it after the **VER280** section and set the version number to **VER300** -> `{$IFDEF VER300}`.

Then try to open the group project file **tmsdXE7group.groupproj** for `Delphi XE7` in `Delphi 10 Seattle` and install the components as any other ones (right click on the five package names in project view -> compile, then -> install.

Don't forget to add the neccesary paths to the library path:
Tools -> Options -> Environment options -> Delphi options -> Library -> select "32-Bit-Windows" if necessary -> Library path -> Button [...]:

- Path of TMS Component pack install folder, e.g. C:\TMS Component Pack
- install folder\Delphi10Seattle\Win32\Release (maybe you have to use DelphiXE7 instead)
- install folder\XlsAdapter

[Compiler versions documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Compiler_Versions)

Comment: I have the source code but when I try to install it on the current version Delphi shows this error: [dcc32 Fatal Error] TMSDXE7.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'tmsdXE7' must be recompiled

Comment: Have you tried to build or compile it before install?

Comment: Yes, It's clear from the error message but it shows the same error again.